# Why are none of my conditions being met in this proc?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So i have a stored procedure (that's been watered down below for demo purposes) that aren't passing any conditions and thus aren't inserting/passing any values into my table. I've tried converting the varchar/string that is being passed in by Java to a number but nothing is working. Below is my 'simplified code'

```
Create or Replace Procedure SAMPLE(rValue IN VARCHAR)
IS
v_Max value.value%type;
v_forecast value.value%type;
BEGIN
--
SELECT BUFFER_MAX_VALUE
 INTO v_MAX
 FROM look_up;
--
EXCEPTION 
WHEN no_data_found
THEN SELECT 0
    INTO v_forecast
    FROM DUAL;
--
 IF to_Number(rValue) < 0 OR to_Number(rValue) > v_MAX) 
 THEN 
 dbms_output.put_line('IF1 Works');
 insert into value(value_id, value)
           values(1, rValue);
ELSIF rValue is null OR to_Number(rValue) = 0
 THEN
dbms_output.put_line('IF1A ONLY Works');
 END IF;
ELSE
insert into value(value_id, value)
           values(1, v_forecast);
dbms_output.put_line('IF1 ELSE ONLY Works');
END SAMPLE;
```

i tried passing the following in:

```
BEGIN
SAMPLE('-7');
END;
```

Comment: What is `v_Max`? And what is dbms_output reporting (the else?)?

Comment: v_Max is just the value that I'm deriving for my IF comparison. If the value that I'm passing in is greater than the v_Max or less than 0, the first dbms_output string should be printed. Not quite sure what you are asking in your second question

Comment: I'm asking if this spits out "IF1 ELSE ONLY Works"? Like the other two conditions are failing and only the `ELSE` is tripping, or if  nothing trips at all? But... I mean I see where the oddity is. The first condition should trip as rValue is -7.

Comment: nothing is printing at all. i'm wondering if it has something to do with the EXCEPTION?

Comment: I was able to comment out the EXCEPTION, and it seems to work. Is there a way I can assign a default value to this variable without the EXCEPTION method (that seems to be throwing everything off)?

Comment: yes i've set serveroutput on , haha! that's one of the basic steps. Thanks for the reminder though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first `SELECT BUFFER_MAX_VALUE` returns anything, nothing else will be executed because you put absolutely *everything* into the `EXCEPTION` section. If you meant to handle that statement only, you should have enclosed it into its own BEGIN-END block, such as

```
create procedure ...
begin
  -- its own begin starts now
  begin
    select buffer_max_value into v_max
    from look_up;
  exception
    when no_data_found then 
      -- do something here
  end;
  -- its own end ends now

  -- put the rest of your code here
end;
```

By the way, does LOOK_UP table contain no rows or only one row, always? Because, as `SELECT` you wrote contains no `WHERE` clause, it might raise `TOO_MANY_ROWS` (which you should also handle).

You declared `rValue` as `VARCHAR2`, and then apply `TO_NUMBER` to it. Why don't you declare it to be a `NUMBER`, instead? Because, nothing prevents you from passing, for example, 'XYZ' to the procedure, and then `TO_NUMBER` will miserably fail with the `INVALID NUMBER` error.

**[EDIT: some more exception handling]**

`EXCEPTION` section handles all exceptions that happen in that `BEGIN-END` block, no matter how many `SELECT` statements you have. Though, you won't know which one failed, unless you include a little bit of additional (simple) programming.

Note that this is just for showing what I meant; don't handle errors with `DBMS_OUTPUT` (as, most probably, nobody will see it), and rarely you'd want to handle errors with `WHEN OTHERS`.

```
create procedure ...
  l_position number;
begin
  l_position := 1;
  select ... into ... from ...;

  l_position := 2;
  select ... into ... 

exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('Error on position ' || l_position ||' '|| sqlerrm);
    raise;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot. The Java program is passing in a STRING and they can't change it to a NUMERIC (or they flat out refuse to). The assumption is that they are never going to pass in any non-numeric characters (this is a REALLY FUNKY WAY of doing things i know). If i have multiple 'select into statements' (in my real code i have multiple variables), will the exception apply to all of the variables even if i put it after all of the 'select intos'? or would i need to put one in for each variable?  I would guess that it's the former but just making sure.

Comment: I added some more info into my message; have a look.

Comment: thanks LittleFoot. So am I following the same format as your first block of code? (Where I BEGIN  / END before and after all variable definitions (respectively))?

Comment: Yes, if you want to handle each of them separately.

Comment: what if I want all of them to be handled that same way?

Comment: Thanks. So each variable definition needs a BEGIN / END and there is no way around it, correct ? (sorry just making sure )

Comment: Well, it is almost midnight here so my brain doesn't work on a high level, but - I'd say not, there's no shortcut. One "general" EXCEPTION section handles all errors for the whole BEGIN-END block, but - if you want to handle each SELECT separately, then you'll have to enclose each of them into its own BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END.

Comment: JEEZ! thanks, just thought i was missing something. Good night!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you wanted the exception section to trap the situation where there is nothing in the lookup table. In that case, you set v_forecast and then continue. That means you need to put the select inside its own block.

I also avoiding multiple to_number calls by setting a constant.

I got rid of the unnecessary select from dual.

I also really really hope that you do not have a table named VALUE with a column named VALUE. Choose more meaningful names.

See how this works for you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sample (rvalue IN VARCHAR2)
IS
   c_rvalue   CONSTANT NUMBER := rvalue;
   v_max               VALUE.VALUE%TYPE;
   v_forecast          VALUE.VALUE%TYPE;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT buffer_max_value INTO v_max FROM look_up;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         v_forecast := 0;
   END;

   IF c_rvalue < 0 OR c_rvalue > v_max
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('IF1 Works');

      INSERT INTO VALUE (value_id, VALUE)
           VALUES (1, rvalue);
   ELSIF c_rvalue IS NULL OR c_rvalue = 0
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('IF1A ONLY Works');
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO VALUE (value_id, VALUE)
           VALUES (1, v_forecast);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('IF1 ELSE ONLY Works');
   END IF;
END sample;
```